# Visual Studio Extension icon in Text Editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

How to insert icon with click events or custom button in editor.
I want create control that looks like R# or CodeRush, and then click on icon open smart tag.
Sorry for my bad English.
Thank you.

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

I create smart tags, but have standard mark on text or standard refactoring mark. I want custom button smart tags.

Comment: You really need to provide more detail. What have you tried so far?

Comment: An icon is an image, it can't have click events, I have no idea what R#/CodeRush is either, you should update your question to include much more detail

Comment: Hello. Added screenshots.

Comment: I create smart tags, but have standard mark on text or standard refactoring mark. I want custom button smart tags.

Comment: Have you looked at the Visual Studio SDKs?

Comment: Sure, i used SDK 2012

Comment: @Sayse No need to explain what is CodeRush or R#, they should be well known for an active C# VS 2012 developer (even if they don't use them, like me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are creating your smart tags, you can set [ISmartTagSession.IconSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense.ismarttagsession.iconsource.aspx) to set the icon you want to show.

Comment: It is iconsource for one smarttag in list? I want icon before open smart tags.

Comment: May create and insert button on view, but how open smarttags on click?

Comment: The session is the top-level item, that contains the list of actions. Each smart tag action also has a separate icon property. Your other question isn't clear, but if it's not related to this it's best to close this question and start a new one.

Comment: Yes, thanks. 
But how to set position or coordinate for button? He render in bottom of char.

Comment: The button will render in the standard place. You can change which character it aligns to, but that's all. If you want to drop it in a random place, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

I create usercontrol and insert in editor.
Old control SmartTag remove.
How to add smart tag action in my usercontol? Control have menu, but cant add SmartTagActions.
How do I make my control was created instead of the standard? Standart control is always created.

```
private bool ButtonSmartTag(ITextView view)
    {
        foreach (ISmartTagSession s in _broke.GetSessions(view))
        {
            var wpfTextView = (IWpfTextView)view;               
            var adornmentLayer = wpfTextView.GetAdornmentLayer("SmartTag");

            foreach (var alement in adornmentLayer.Elements)
            {
                adornmentLayer.RemoveAllAdornments();

                var line = view.GetTextViewLineContainingBufferPosition(_view.Caret.Position.BufferPosition);
                alement.VisualSpan, "butRe", but, null);

                var mb = new ReButtonMenu();
                mb.Margin = new Thickness(0, line.Top, 0, 0);
                adornmentLayer.AddAdornment(AdornmentPositioningBehavior.TextRelative, alement.VisualSpan, "butRe", mb, null);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```